# How Do I Make .Exe Duplicate Itself in C++?

Tags: c++, exe

I'm new to C++ and I want my application to duplicate itself once or twice when executed. I've searched on this forum for this topic, and had no luck.So I hope I'm not digging up something thats already been discussed. The code I've got so far is below, and I'm just experimenting and trying to see what different things i can do in C++ - the program I'm making has no practical use.
The code I've got so far as below.

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream.h>

void main()

{
    int id;
    cout << "Hello\n";
    cin >> id;

    cout << "Testing" << id << endl;

 int i=0;
 do
 {
   i++;
   fstream feck ("lucinada.doc", fstream::in | fstream::out);
   feck << "testing";
24
 }while(i<100);


 int j=0;

 do

 {

   j++;

   fstream feck ("ludacris.doc", fstream::in | fstream::out);

   feck << "testing";

 }while(j<100);



 int k=2;
 do
 {

   k++;

   fstream feck ("400l.doc", fstream::in | fstream::out);

   feck << "testing";}while(k<100);}
```

How can i duplicate my application .exe to multiple path.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd suspect you are looking for [`fork()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - The OP's code has `#include <windows.h>` at the top...

Comment: @Smeeheey IIRC, `fork()` is supported on Windows as well.

Comment: _@mehrdad_ You should elaborate what exactly you mean the program should _duplicate itself_. Do you want to copy it somewhere else to your harddisk, or do you want to have multiple copies of it running at the same time?

Comment: I want to copy it somewhere else to my harddisk. i want copy my program .EXE file.

Comment: @mehrdad: why do you want to do this?

Comment: why? what you mean

Answer (score 1):

Get the path to your executable file by using [GetModuleFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) then copy it using [CopyFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This solution will only work under Windows of course but as far as it goes for filesystem operations you'll always have to implement them for each OS (unless you use something like boost::filesystem).

Answer (score 1):

Use GetModuleFileName to get the path of your exe, then use CopyFile to copy it to a new destination.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197(v=vs.85).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851(v=vs.85).aspx